# Unable to assign std::lower_bound return value to vector::iterater

Tags: c++, vector, types, constants

Passed into function: const std::vector &xv:

```
std::vector<float>::iterator lowBound = lower_bound(xv.begin(), xv.end(), x);
```

The function worked fine before i changed the `std::vector<float>&` to a `const std::vector<float>&`

`Lower_bound` returns syntax error at compile time saying:

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const float *, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>>>" to "__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float *, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>>>" exists
std::vector<...>::const_iterator std::lower_bound<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>>::const_iterator, float>(std::vector<...>::const_iterator __first, std::vector<...>::const_iterator __last, const float &__val)
```

I have tried changing `std::vector<float>::iterator` to `const std::vector<float>::iterator` and have also tried `std::vector<const float>::iterator`.

None of these options seem to work.

Im sorry for the trouble, ive tried googling the error and could not come up with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lower_bound` returns a `const_iterator`. You need

```
std::vector<float>::const_iterator lowBound = lower_bound(xv.begin(), xv.end(), x);
```

or simply (C++11)

```
auto lowBound = lower_bound(xv.begin(), xv.end(), x);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://cpp.sh/7aowp)

Comment: Thank you very much. I just saw this online right as you posted it. I didnt know that `const_iterator` was different from `const vector<>::iterator`. Are there any instances where you would use `const vector<>::iterator`?

Comment: `const vector<float>::iterator` means the iterator is const; `vector<float>::const_iterator` means the element pointed to is const.

Comment: `vector<float>::const_iterator` is more often used.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was supposed to use:

`std::vector<float>::const_iterator` instead of const `std::vector<float>::iterator`.

Didn't know that there was a separate data type.

So the answer is: `std::vector<float>::const_iterator`